# optaplanner ValueRangeProvider configuration

Tags: optaplanner

Is it possible to configure ValueRangeProvider in such a way that, when engine calls getter of the valueRange, I can somehow know which instance of PlanningEntity is in question, so that I can change the range based on this info.

To make it clearer, for timetabling, I would like to know which "Lecture" is calling CourseSchedule.getRoomList function, then, I will give a smaller roomlist, based on other details of Lecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called **value range provider from entity** (instead of from solution). See docs.